# My team and reports

Tags: force.com, reporting

Quick question on reports. Reports on custom objects have an option to show "my team's custom_object_name"

What drives the my team? is it role? can it be something aside from role? if it's important this object is related by look up to case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The visibility is indeed decided on the role, that is, if the sharing settings of that particular custom object are on private.

Where My Team's "custom object", are all your records, and all records of team members beneath you in the role hierarchy.

Comment: no, none of them are below me on the role hierarchy.  Is that the way the my team works? it shows people ONLY below you (in the role heirarcy), AND you, but nobody else assigned to your role (in the heirarchy)?

Comment: yes, this is how roles work, on all objects. if nobody is below you, you only see your records

Comment: So how many levels down in the role heiarchy  does the "my team" go ? 1 level, or until there are no more subbordinates?

Comment: as deep as the roles go.

Comment: Do sharing rules impact what is seen in My Teams?